# NodeJS express routing with router

Tags: node.js, express

I have generated node project with express generator

#### Main app.js file

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var detailRouter = require('./routes/user-detail');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/users/:userId', detailRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

#### user details router file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) =>{
  res.send("Name is:"+req.params.userId);
})
module.exports = router;
```

when I am running running the application with npm start
I am getting the req.params.userdId == undefned

Is something wrong with code or I am missing something.

Also when i use below code in app.js it works perfectly fine

```
app.get('/users/:userid', (req,res,next) => {
  res.send(req.params);
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have done mistake. Params means you need to pass some paramenter in the url. like below

```
app.use('/:userId', indexRouter);
```

And need to change

```
router.get('/:userId', (req, res, next) =>{
      res.send("Name is:"+req.params.userId);
})
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks
However, is this is the only way? Because if I have one more path example '/test' then if i hit localhost:3000/test/harsh or localhost:3000/users/harsh

Both will go to '/:userId'
correct me If I am wrong. Is there any way to define path with hierarchy?
Thanks

Comment: you can use RequestBody and you can pass your data

Comment: if you got the answer then you can accept my answer

Comment: Didn't get you "RequestBody" is related with POST. How can i use it in GET call. I think you didn't get my question.

Example: '/test' ,'/users' , '/:userId' in these both cases it will work.
This is kind of standalone path

Does node provide something like
'/users/:userId' ? If not then is post or queryParams are only options?

Comment: that's what i am talking, if you are using `/users/:userId` then you need to use `req.params.userId` otherwise use post

Comment: Okay for now, I didn't find better solution than '
app.get('/:userId') so accepting the solution.
If someone find better solution please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the values of parameters passed by GET through the url, do

`const { id } = req.query`

In this case you could access the parameter value passed in the URL:

`http://yoursite.com/users?id=somevalue`

Comment: thanks Kristian however i don''t want to pass value as query

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [Sangram's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6662421/sangram-badi) answer, you can also use route method along with instance of Router for much cleaner readable code like below.

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import {
  readOne,
  updateOne,
  deleteOne
} from './controller';

const router = new Router();
router
  .route('/:id')
  .get(readOne)
  .put(updateOne)
  .delete(deleteOne);

export default router;
```